# setFocus na coluna da grid com o nome do campo que esta no banco

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, delphi-7, grid, dbgrid

Quando tento colocar o foco para uma coluna especifica pelo nome do campo no banco, não da certo.

Porem se eu fizer colocando o numero da ordem da coluna, exemplo coluna 4, ai da certo, mas queria pelo nome do campo.

Eu desejava dessa forma, porem assim ele não da o foco:

```
if condicao then
  grdAjuste.SetFocus('id_codigo');
```

Agora se eu fizer assim, funciona corretamente:

```
if condicao then
  grdAjuste.SetFocus(4);
```

Porem acho que essa última forma não é muito correta.

Como eu poderia por o foco corretamente no campo por meio do seu nome?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
grdAjuste.SelectedField := cdsDados.FieldByName('id_codigo');
```

Comment: obrigado parceiro